# Сделать сложную выборку из базы MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c0aef4/2

Есть таблица move, в ней фиксируются все перемещения техники со склада на пользователей и обратно.

Хочу получить информацию по всей технике у пользователя На сегодняшний день.  Что сейчас физически у него.
В данном примере, в отчет должны попасть две строки, id 3 и 6

А вообще в таблице будет тысячи перемещений разной техники.

Вот с таким select попадает только одна строка id 6
Помогите плиз модифицировать запрос

```
SELECT * 
FROM move as m 
WHERE m.placeNew = 'Иванов Иван' 
  and m.date = (select max(date) 
                from move 
                where placeNew = m.placeNew
               );
```

Comment: Если данные согласованы, достаточно отобрать те позиции, для которых COUNT нечётный.

Comment: Это в данном примере 3 и 6 , в таблице будет тысячи перемещений разной техники.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT move.*
FROM move, 
(
    SELECT name, MAX(date) maxdate
    FROM move
    GROUP BY name
) subq
WHERE move.name = subq.name
  AND move.date = subq.maxdate
  AND move.placeNew = 'Иванов Иван';
```

Comment: спс огромное, помогло